# Can all non-archimedean groups be written as a product of archimedean groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders, ordered-groups

We say that a partially ordered group $(G,\cdot, \geq)$ is Archimedean if for any $g,h >1\in G$ there exists some n such that $g^n > h$.

All the non-archimedean groups I know of can be written as the product of archimedean groups. I'm wondering if this is generally true. I think I've found a proof, but I haven't heard this theorem anywhere, so I suspect my proof is flawed.

Proof: We know that convex subgroups can be ordered under inclusion. Say we have convex subgroups $H_1\subset H_2$; let $h_1,\dots$ be the generators of $H_1$, $a_1,\dots$ be the generators of $H_2$ not in $H_1$ and A the group generated by $a_1,\dots$. I claim that $H_2 \cong A\times H_1$ because there is a homomorphism $f(a_1+\dots+h_1+\dots)=(a_1+\dots,h_1+\dots)$. The kernel of $f$ is 0, so $f$ is an isomorphism. QED.

Is this correct?

Comment: Ignoring order theory, how can $H_2\setminus H_1$ be a subgroup of $H_2$?

Comment: @Anon: good point, I misspoke. Please see my update.

Comment: What does this mean, "the generators of $H_2$ not in $H_1$"?  Actually, what do you mean in general by "the generators"?  A group has lots of possible generating sets, one of which is all of the elements of the group, but your proof seems to have some specific idea in mind about these generators.

Comment: What about the $p$-adic integers?

Comment: @Jim: Good point. I guess I wanted not only $a_1,\dots$ to not be in $H_1$ but also $A$ to be disjoint from $H_1$, which obviously isn't true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having thought about this for the last year and finally proven a very similar theorem, I discovered that this is actually known and is called the [Hahn embedding theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_embedding_theorem). So it's not true that any group is isomorphic to $\mathbb R ^\Omega$, but they all can at least be o-embedded in it.