# Why are the p-adic integers a linearly ordered group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, order-theory, p-adic-number-theory

In a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392039/can-all-non-archimedean-groups-be-written-as-a-product-of-archimedean-groups), someone suggested the p-adic integers as an example of a non-archimedean linearly ordered group.

I'm not sure why these are linearly ordered - specifically, it doesn't seem to me like there would be a total order. E.g. under the 3-adic norm I think $1\leq 4$ and $4\leq 1$ (since $3^0$ is the highest that divides both) yet $1\not = 4$ so it's not total.

When you talk about the "p-adic" integers as an ordered group, is it implied that you "mod out" everything which isn't a power of $p$ so that the order is total?

Comment: The order of the $p$-adic integers does not come from the $p$-adic norm.

Comment: You’re not going to be able to get an explicit order: see the accepted answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/49990/12042).